# Игнорирование очень маленьких чисел с плавающей запятой

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    long double func(long double a, int k)
    {
        long double s=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
            s*=a+2*(i-1);
        return s;
    }
    long long fact(long long x)
    {
        if(x==0)
            return 1;
        return x*fact(x-1);
    }
    int main()
    {
        long double x,a,e,s,q,w;
        int k = 3;
        cin >> x;
        cin >> a;
        cin >> e;
        s=1;//сумматор
            /*вычисляю два первых члена ряда*/
            q=func(a,1)/(fact(1)*fact(1))*pow(x,1);
            w=func(a,2)/(fact(3)*fact(2))*pow(x,2);
            s=s+q+w;
        while(w-q<e)
        {
            q=w;
            w=func(a,k)/(fact(2*k-1)*fact(k))*pow(x,k);
            s+=func(a,k)/(fact(2*k-1)*fact(k))*pow(x,k);
            cout<<"s="<< s<<endl;
            k++;
        }
        cout << s << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Есть такой код, он вычисляет сумму `S` при задаваемых `x` и `a` с точностью `e`.
Но после 3-й итерации сумматор перестает добавлять к себе числа меньше `10^-6`.Как это исправить?

Comment: видимо потому, что s слишком большой.

Comment: s на 3 итерации равен 2.27172(при x=1,a=1,e=0,001)

Comment: А что, собственно, за ряд вычисляется? :)

Comment: @Harry добавил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уважаемый,

```
cout << s;
```

по умолчанию выводит **только 6 знаков**...

Напишите, например,

```
cout << setprecision(10) << s;
```

Вот как делал бы я:

```
double sum(double x, double a, double eps)
{
    double term = a*x;
    double sum = 1.0 + term;
    for(int k = 1;abs(term) > eps;++k)
    {
        sum += term *= (a+2*k)*x/(2*k*(2*k+1)*(k+1));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Кстати, этот ряд равен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48461/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-------).